# SSRS Table Row Count increasing on each page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

So I have a table on a sub report that on the first page has 3 rows of data like this.
(I would post pictures but it wont let me)

```
Column        Column 2             Column 3
1                4                    7
2                5                    8
3                6                    9
```

Then on the next page the table looks like this.

```
Column        Column 2             Column 3
  1              4                    7
  2              5                    8
  3              6                    9
  1              4                    7
  2              5                    8
  3              6                    9
```

And so on. Each page has the 3 rows repeated an extra time. The data is all correct at least. Anyone know what could be causing this to happen?
*edited the data to be a little easier to understand

Comment: What do you have for your PageBreak values on the tablix?

Comment: None of them are set, so i guess default.